How to create an R2RML where both the subject and object are constants?
I am using RDFizer to create triples from R2RML but I am first trying to create some nodes of provenance which are both constants. I am building an automated R2RML generation service and these provenance nodes will always be at the top before we ingest the data. The R2RML runs without errors but produces no triples.
Here is what I have so far:
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .

<#TestMapping> a rr:TriplesMap;
    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:constant ex:testSubject ;
    ] ;
    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate ex:testPredicate ;
        rr:objectMap [
            rr:constant ex:testObject ;
        ]
    ] .

I expected to receive:
<http://example.org/testSubject> <http://example.org/testPredicate> <http://example.org/testObject>


share your actual output
